# How to display step count extracted from a galaxy watch 4

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to develop an app that will display step count that was extracted from galaxy watch 4. The application will ask you to authenticate with google and once you authenticated it will display the step count that will extracted from the galaxy watch 4. But right now nothing happen once you authenticated with google, it does not even display a successful authentication message.

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Bucket;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataPoint;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSet;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataReadRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataReadResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "GoogleFitDemo";
    private static final int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
    private FitnessOptions fitnessOptions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Configure Google Sign-In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(Fitness.SCOPE_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE)
                .build();
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        // Configure Fitness Options
        fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();

        // Set click listener for the authentication button
        Button authButton = findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
        authButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Authentication successful");
                accessGoogleFitApi();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Authentication failed");
            }
        }
    }


    private void accessGoogleFitApi() {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);

        // Use the account to access the Google Fit API
        // For example, you can use the HistoryClient to retrieve step count
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, account)
                .readData(new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                        .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                        .setTimeRange(1, System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
                        if (dataReadResponse.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
                            // Get step count from buckets
                            for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResponse.getBuckets()) {
                                List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                                for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                                    for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                                        int stepCount = dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                                        // Update UI with step count from Galaxy Watch 4
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Step count from bucket: " + stepCount);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (dataReadResponse.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
                            // Get step count from data sets
                            for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResponse.getDataSets()) {
                                for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                                    int stepCount = dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                                    // Update UI with step count from Galaxy Watch 4
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Step count from data set: " + stepCount);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read step count", e);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```